# Upgrading Brakes

Tags: brakes, cyclocross

I'm new to biking having had to give up running due to 'worn out' knee joints!  I bought an entry level cyclo-cross Carrera Crixus from Halfords which I love.  My only criticism of the bike is the poor braking performance, I live on the edge of the Brecon Beacons and ride a mixture of road and track with some very steep hills thrown into the mix.  I don't have vast amounts of spare cash to upgrade to another bike, but wondered whether it's feasible and cost effective to upgrade from caliper to disc brakes on this bike - any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The short answer is no. You'd need a fork with mounting points. They are also missing at the rear.

Comment: Fairly sure this has been asked before, although I couldn't find anything from a quick search. @Carel is right, if you want to upgrade your existing brakes you will probably have more joy staying with rim brakes